# stack-based pointer stored on object vector has long-life-term?

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory, stack-memory

Give the example:

```
class A
{
public:
    int value;
    A():value(1){};
    ~A(){};
};

void Display( std::vector<A> myvector )
{
    for( std::vector<A>::iterator it = myvector.begin(); it!= myvector.end(); ++it )
        std::cout << (*it).value << std::endl;
}

A* GetAtId( DWORD id )
{
    if( id != 0 )
    {
        static A ret;
        return& ret;
    }

    return NULL;
}


void Serialize( DWORD obj[3] )
{
    std::vector<A> vecHold;

    for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
    {
        A* ptr = NULL;
        if( obj[i] != 0 )
        {
            ptr = GetAtId( obj[i] );
            if( ptr ) vecHold.push_back( *ptr );
        }
    }

    Display( vecHold );
}

int main( )
{

    DWORD id[3] = {0,};
    id[2] = 9;
    Serialize( id );
}
```

Does it 'survives' for a call to `Display`? (Not that this is what I mean by 'long-life term')

Because the pointer is deallocated at the next bracket.
I know a vector storing pointers such as `std::vector<A*>vecHold`, `vecHold.push_back( ptr )` would be illegal, but what about in this case?

Comment: `return& ret;` -- ugh, what's with that formatting? You're taking the address of `ret`, the `&` should definitly not be grouped with the `return` ... Then, how about you get a book that explains value semantics? This isn't Java or C# where everything is a reference, so of course there are always copies (or moves in C++11) involved when you have plain value types.

Comment: Please use references instead of pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vecHold.push_back( *ptr );
```

Creates a copy of the object pointed by `ptr`(`ret`) and then adds it in to the vector `vecHold`. `ret` is a local `static` object which remains valid and has the lifetime same as the lifetime of your program. So `vecHold` holds a valid object and there is nothing incorrect w.r.t in the program.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I would like know!

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is declared as `static` inside a function, it means that its lifetime will last the whole time of the program. So in this case it's safe to return and store pointers or references to it.

Comment: What if it returned a temporary pointer to it, would it still be save to store references?

Comment: Temporary pointer is irrelevant. If you didn't return by value, it's safe to use.

Comment: It safe to store a reference as long as the object being referred to still exists. Your `static A ref;` exists till the program exits so there's no problem.

Comment: @john but as Als said, `push_back` creates a copy of the object, so it should be safe to store it anyways

Comment: @ViniyoShouta, yes that's correct. I thought your vector was a vector of pointers not a vector of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a copy of the vector. Vectors are not automatically passed by reference (nor is anything else I can think of). If you want a reference then write the code to use one.